# Posterior update for continuous bernoulli

Tags: bayesian, posterior, beta-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

The [continuous Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Bernoulli_distribution#Beta_distribution) extends the usual Bernoulli distribution by allowing outcome values in $[0,1]$ rather than in $\{0,1\}$. For bias parameter $p$, its pdf is the same as the pmf of the Bernoulli, except allowing $x\in [0,1]$: $$P(x|p) \propto p^x (1-p)^{1-x}.$$

Now the usual way to update the posterior distribution on the bias $p$ is $$\text{Beta}(a + \text{#heads}, b + \text{#tails})$$ where $\text{Beta}(a,b)$ is the prior.

How is the posterior updated in the continuous case?

Would it be $Beta(a,b) \mapsto Beta(a+x, b+(1-x))$ for $x\sim \text{contBern}(p)$?

Comment: The beta distribution is not the conjugate prior for the continuous Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Really? What is, then?